# Recipe to compute dimension and decompose product of $SO(N)$ group representations

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras, representation-theory

As it is well known Young tableaux (YT) provide an efficient and very useful way to treat $SU(N)$ representation. This is principally based on these facts:

1. There is a correspondence between irreps of $SU(N)$ and YT;
2. There is an easy way to compute dimension of a certain irrep of $SU(N)$ (using again YT);
3. There is an easy algorithm to multiply two or more irreps of $SU(N)$ in terms of YT;

**Questions**: Is there a way to do the same (points 1. 2. 3.) with $SO(N)$? What are the algorithms to do that?

Comment: This seems to be a pure math question.

Comment: Yes, indeed is a math question, but I'm sure that mathematicians are not interested in this sort of things. I think it is more likely that a physicist that _uses_ very much group theory cold know the practical recipe.

Comment: As explained [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/30617/recipe-compute-dimension-decompose-product-representations?show=30718#a30718), some kind of Young Tableaux exist in this case too, but they are more restricted.